# want to use basicget rabbitmq function in node.js

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am new learner trying to understand rabbitmq in node.js.
To consume a message from queue can I use channel.basic_get which is available in python in node.js. 
If yes please suggest how to use it? I am not able to find syntax for get api in node.js to consume message from rabbitmq.

NOTE: I dont want to use channel.consume()

Comment: "NOTE: I dont want to use channel.consume()" why?

Comment: since channel.consume() will be blocked if there is no message in the queue. But I want to implement such a way that it should not be blocked if there is no message in the queue.

Comment: and in which way you know when there are messages to consume ?

Comment: continuously looping through the program, after sleeping for some time again will call get function to consume the message.

Answer (score 0):

use the `amqplib` node module (aka "node.amqp") and it has the `get` method that you want:

http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_get

Comment: amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn)
        {
        conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
        var q = 'hello';
        ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
        console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);
        ch.get(q,[{noAck: false},[function(msg)
                {
                console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
                ch.ack(msg);
                }]]);
        });
unable to print the message on console....please suggest correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

the problem with the code is I have not closed the square bracket "]" after {noack:false}. So due to that it was assuming the rest of the code also as options and its not printing the output on console. I am pasting the working code below:

```
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) 
{ 
conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) { 
var q = 'hello'; 
ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false}); 
console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q); 
ch.get(q,**[{noAck: false}]**,function(msg) { console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString()); ch.ack(msg); });
});
});
```